# How to provide hostName into Docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I wrote simple server

```
const http = require("http");

http
  .createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.end("Hello from server world!");
  })
  .listen(3000);
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16
COPY . .
WORKDIR /

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

so after commands

```
docker build . -t test/0.0.0.0
docker images
docker run -p 3000:3000 containerIdHere
```

server is accessible from  localhost:3000  and from  127.0.0.1:3000 and even from whole range since 127 for example 127.1.1.1:3000
But if after I will add server host addres in server.js like this

```
const http = require("http");

http
  .createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.end("Hello from 127.0.0.1 dcoker");
  })
  .listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
```

there will be no access to the server using Docker but without everything works
and even with -h flag

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -h 127.0.0.1  b3ea4137b817
```

no acces
the structure of server is really only 2 files like on the image[image]

is that possible to make a server with provided hostName accessible using Docker?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Starting your server bound to `127.0.0.1` binds port 3000 on the **container's** `localhost` interface only. If you want to bind the **host** port to the `localhost` interface only, use `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000`

Comment: you should listen on 0.0.0.0 (which is what node does by default). however, if you want to hack it, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513336/is-there-a-way-to-expose-a-docker-container-port-bound-to-127-0-0-1-to-host#answer-52518929